# Remedy for java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'Centres'

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils, nosuchmethod

I am working on a project based on Struts2. I have a POJO called `AddCentreNestedForm` which has one of the property of type String[] called `Centres`.

So

```
public class AddCentreNestedForm{

....
....
private String[] Centres = new String[]{"-1","-1","-1","-1","-1","-1"};
...
...
public String[] getCentres(){
   return Centres;
}
public void setCentres(String[] Centres){
   this.Centres = Centres;
}

}
```

Now in the action class, i have a statement like below:

```
String[] centres =null;
...
...

centres = BeanUtils.getArrayProperty(addCentreNestedForm, "Centres");
```

on this line, it gives exception :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'Centres'
```

'addCentreNestedForm' is an instance of POJO AddCentreNestedForm.

I debugged the application, when this line is executed, the value of `Centres` is `{"Centres","-1"}.`

On googling this exception, it mentions that this exception occurs when `BeanUtils` is not able to find proper getter method for the mentioned property.

Please let me know what should be the getter method name, I have named it as 'getCentres()'. Please let me know if there is any other solution to this problem.

Comment: Change your field name in `AddCentreNestedForm` to lower case `centres`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tired option of making 'Centres' property to 'centres', but after doing so, the value from jsp to POJO's property stopped being populated. I also made changes into jsp page and converted 'Centres' to 'centres' but of no help. Then I tried a simple solution and it worked. I simple used the getter method i.e. getCentres() and it worked. So I removed the line containing BeanUtils and instead, fetched the value from getCentres().

Answer (score 2):

Try `centers` rather than `Centers`. Properties are assumed to be in camel case.